# Computational Complexity

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

"Why are additions known to be cheaper than multiplications?"

In contexts pertaining to algebraic complexity theory, this statement is often cited. Can someone elaborate on this? I don't understand the reason behind multiplications being more expensive than additions.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean cheaper or more expensive??

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I'm sorry.I have edited the question. I meant why are additions cheaper than multiplications.

Answer (score 3):

This a very good question, and the answer is surprinsingly an open problem in Theoretical Computer Science. In a nutshell: one can do addition in linear time, and the best known upper bound for multiplication is (approximately) $O(n\log n)$. But there is no proof that multiplication cannot be done in linear time.

You should look at [Is there a proof that addition is faster than multiplication?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12671/is-there-a-proof-that-addition-is-faster-than-multiplication) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, because in order to perform a multiplication, you need many additions:

$$
M \times N = \underbrace{M + \ldots + M}_{N \text{ times}}
$$
for $M,N$ integers.

Comment: In my opinion, cheaper means "taking lesser time" (in context of computational complexity). How does performing more additions solve the problem?

Comment: Usually, multiplication is considered more expensive than addition, not cheaper

Comment: I have edited the question. I meant this only.